# Plot 2 different dataframe into 1 plot and set custom x-axis with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a plot from 2 different df

my code:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(data=df.temp1, aes(x = sample2, y=delta_rn)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), axis.title = element_text(size=20),axis.text=element_text(size=15),
        axis.text.x=element_text(angle = -40, hjust = 0))+
  geom_boxplot(data=df.temp2, aes(x = 'rn',y=delta_rn))
```

df1:

```
structure(list(sample2 = c("p10_065", "p10_065", "p10_065", "p10_065", 
"p10_065", "p10_065", "p10_065", "p10_065", "p10_065", "p39_080", 
"p39_080", "p39_080", "p39_080", "p39_080", "p39_080", "p39_080", 
"p39_080", "p39_080", "s36_068", "s36_068", "s36_068", "s36_068", 
"s36_068", "s36_068", "s36_068", "s36_068", "s36_068", "s32_066", 
"s32_066", "s32_066", "s32_066", "s32_066", "s32_066", "s32_066", 
"s32_066", "s32_066", "s43_078", "s43_078", "s43_078", "s43_078", 
"s43_078", "s43_078", "s43_078", "s43_078", "s43_078", "s29_083", 
"s29_083", "s29_083", "s29_083", "s29_083", "s29_083", "s29_083", 
"s29_083", "s29_083", "p1_065", "p1_065", "p1_065", "p1_065", 
"p1_065", "p1_065", "p1_065", "p1_065", "p1_065", "p2_080", "p2_080", 
"p2_080", "p2_080", "p2_080", "p2_080", "p2_080", "p2_080", "p2_080", 
"s21_077", "s21_077", "s21_077", "s21_077", "s21_077", "s21_077", 
"s21_077", "s21_077", "s21_077", "p41_072", "p41_072", "p41_072", 
"p41_072", "p41_072", "p41_072", "p41_072", "p41_072", "p41_072", 
"s22_066", "s22_066", "s22_066", "s22_066", "s22_066", "s22_066", 
"s22_066", "s22_066", "s22_066"), delta_rn = c(7588L, 15153L, 
22729L, 30292L, 37867L, 45444L, 53017L, 60585L, 68154L, 6319L, 
12628L, 18929L, 25238L, 31545L, 37853L, 44159L, 50463L, 56773L, 
9066L, 18123L, 27179L, 36233L, 45292L, 54341L, 63398L, 72453L, 
81513L, 11135L, 22266L, 33392L, 44514L, 55641L, 66770L, 77898L, 
89018L, 100148L, 8014L, 16020L, 24018L, 32021L, 40029L, 48030L, 
56032L, 64029L, 72036L, 8175L, 16331L, 24492L, 32649L, 40808L, 
48959L, 57123L, 65275L, 73440L, 18334L, 36667L, 54985L, 73309L, 
91636L, 109959L, 128290L, 146607L, 164931L, 18969L, 37923L, 56882L, 
75830L, 94789L, 113745L, 132695L, 151652L, 170608L, 14462L, 28915L, 
43369L, 57820L, 72276L, 86727L, 101185L, 115632L, 130091L, 18758L, 
37518L, 56268L, 75018L, 93772L, 112529L, 131280L, 150029L, 168782L, 
18311L, 36609L, 54908L, 73206L, 91505L, 109800L, 128099L, 146395L, 
164695L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(102L, 103L, 104L, 
105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 
77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 
40L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 82L, 83L, 
84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 
58L, 59L, 60L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 42L, 
43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L))
```

and df2:

```
structure(list(sample2 = c("p10_065", "p39_080", "s36_068", "s32_066", 
"s43_078", "s29_083", "p1_065", "p2_080", "s21_077", "p41_072", 
"s22_066"), delta_rn = c(5121066L, 6585801L, 2955395L, 0L, 4636924L, 
4271671L, 2699432L, 1884355L, 4851650L, 1846467L, 1588973L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(101L, 
71L, 11L, 21L, 1L, 31L, 91L, 81L, 51L, 61L, 41L))
```

and here is my plot:
[image]

The problem is that my "rn" label is in the middle and I'm unable to custom this x-axis.
It's sorting it alphabetically, but I would like this label which is coming from my second df to be  either at the extreme left or the extreme right of my plot.
So to be more clear I would like to order my label by df...

Comment: I think in the second `geom_boxplot` `x` should be 'rn', not ''?

Comment: yes indeed, small mistake ! I edited it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply create the `labels` and do a manual annotation of the `axis` using `scale_x_discrete(labels= xlabs)`:

```r
xlabs <- c("rn", levels(factor(df1$sample2)))

ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(data=df1, aes(x = sample2, y=delta_rn)) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), axis.title = element_text(size=20),axis.text=element_text(size=15),
        axis.text.x=element_text(angle = -40, hjust = 0))+
  geom_boxplot(data=df2, aes(x = '',y=delta_rn)) +  scale_x_discrete(labels= xlabs)
```

## Output

[image: sample_out_manual]

Comment: Nice trick, since I only have 1 variable for me it's the easiest and best solution !

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you have to combine the two data frames together, and then set the levels, leaving 'rn' to first or last.

```
test = rbind(df1,df2 %>% mutate(sample2='rn'))
test$sample2 = factor(test$sample2,levels=c(unique(df1$sample2),'rn'))

ggplot(data=test,aes(x = sample2, y=delta_rn)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), axis.title = element_text(size=20),axis.text=element_text(size=15),
        axis.text.x=element_text(angle = -40, hjust = 0))
```

[image]

Comment: So I tried your solution, but I had an issue in the 2nd line, for me it wasn't working (R v 3.5.2). I had to correct it this way : `test$sample2 = factor(test$sample2,levels=c(levels(droplevels(df1$sample2)),'rn'))`

Comment: Weird. Ok you must have separated df2 from df1. Otherwise there's no need to droplevels

Comment: I merged the 2 df as you did : `test = rbind(df1,df2 %>% mutate(sample2='rn'))`, but the problem was coming from here `levels=c(unique(df1$sample2),'rn')` it didn't liked it replacing all the variable into 'sample2' by "NA", except for 'rn'

Answer (score 2):

I'd start with binding the data together, setting `sample2` column of the second df to "rn".

```
library(dplyr)
df <- 
  bind_rows(
    df.temp1,
    mutate(df.temp2, sample2 = "rn")
  )


count(df, sample2)

#> # A tibble: 12 x 2
#>    sample2     n
#>    <chr>   <int>
#>  1 p1_065      9
#>  2 p10_065     9
#>  3 p2_080      9
#>  4 p39_080     9
#>  5 p41_072     9
#>  6 rn         11
#>  7 s21_077     9
#>  8 s22_066     9
#>  9 s29_083     9
#> 10 s32_066     9
#> 11 s36_068     9
#> 12 s43_078     9
```

"rn" is indeed alphabetically in the middle, but we can convert this column to factor and set our own order.

```
library(forcats)

df <- 
  df %>% 
  mutate(sample2 = fct_relevel(sample2, "rn", after = 0))

levels(df$sample2)

#>  [1] "rn"      "p1_065"  "p10_065" "p2_080"  "p39_080" "p41_072" "s21_077" "s22_066" "s29_083" "s32_066" "s36_068"
#> [12] "s43_078"
```

This places "rn" to the beginning. If you want it to be at the end, set `after = Inf`.

Now ggplot2 will use the order we defined.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(sample2, delta_rn)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    axis.title = element_text(size=20),
    axis.text=element_text(size=15),
    axis.text.x=element_text(angle = -40, hjust = 0)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: seems to be a more complete solution. Would be a better idea if I had more variable.
Thanks you !